# Create custom soap header using apache.cxf.headers.Header

Tags: java, xml, apache, soap, cxf

I want to create a Soap header structure like following :

```
<soapenv:Header>
      <wataniya:auth xmlns:wataniya="http://osb.wataniya.com">
         <username> TestUser</username>
         <password> TestPassword </password>
      </wataniya:auth>
</soapenv:Header>
```

I have written a code :

```
QName qName = new QName("http://osb.wataniya.com", "auth", "watania"); 

        Element authElement = doc.getDocumentElement();

        Element usernameElement = doc.createElement("username");
        usernameElement.setTextContent("TestUser");

        Element passwordElement = doc.createElement("password");
        passwordElement.setTextContent("TestPassword");

        authElement.appendChild(usernameElement);
        authElement.appendChild(passwordElement);

        Header header =  new Header(qName, authElement);
```

I have used following imports(for reference):

```
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException;
import org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault;
import org.apache.cxf.headers.Header;
import org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault;
import org.apache.cxf.message.MessageContentsList;
import org.w3c.dom.DOMException;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
```

But I am facing issue and unable to generate the header as expected.

Any leads..thanks in advance

Comment: could you post the stacktrace?